# I am using Laravel 5.2, Is there some best suggestion where to put helper function which is being used just in 1 controller,

Tags: laravel, helper

I am using Laravel 5.2, I am using a helper function just in 1 controller, where should I put such function

```
/**
 * trim all elements of array
 * 
 * @param $elements
 * @param string $delimiter
 * @return array
 */
private function trimArrayElements($elements, $delimiter = '|')
{
    return array_map('trim',explode($delimiter, $elements));
}
```

Comment: No matter if you only use it once, just put it to helper.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the function only in that controller I will keep the function in the controller itself, just declare the function private.

Comment: I did the same a private function in the controller, my question is about single Responsibility, it seems like that kind of function must not be in the controller

Comment: If you ask about general programming principles put the function in a custom helpers.php file, the answer from @phaberest is good. With that file you can define every other helper function you'll need. I think that your function is generic enough to deserve being in a global helper. IMHO If you use it only in that controller using a private function is not so wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I usually create a `app/helpers.php` to let me use these tiny functions everywhere.

Then change the `autoload` section of `composer.json` to autoload that file without namespacing it.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

Comment: in the case that will be app level available, but I just need it in a single controller, not everywhere

Comment: If you want to keep your controller clean, then use an external class with the function in a public (or event public static) method.